# Standard reports in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, when right clicking table name, I see only `Custom Reports` as option, `Standard Reports` is not offered. Do I need to have permission for Standard Reports?

Comment: What kind of reporting are you referring to?  SSRS or what?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any at that node. I see "Standard Reports" when clicking a database or the instance node but not at that level.

Comment: @bluefeet - The reports built into SSMS (that do use reporting services)

Comment: Those standard reports are the database level because that is what they are designed to report on. If you want a report that only applies one one table then you'll have to make one. Example there is no use in doing disk usage by table on a single table.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Standard reports available at the table level. Standard reports are available at SQL Server instance and database levels.

Also, Microsoft has created a set of custom reports you can use for free. You can download them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29063)